# Lost Admin rights, Can't reinstall OS since there is a firmware password in Mac

Tags: mac, password, firmware

I have a situation where my user account is now a standard account and I can't change anything because I don't have an Admin account. I can't use Sudo commands since it says user is not in `sudoers` list.
Also I can't even reinstall macOS using a bootable drive since I am required to enter a firmware password which I am not aware of.

To even turn off firmware password, I need to enter recovery mode which I am unable to as I have to enter the Firmware password first.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I have literally tried everything I could find on the internet but its of no use.

Comment: What's the precise Mac model? What OS is on it?

Comment: Hi! Its Macbook Pro (Late 2011) High Sierra. 

I can't enter single user mode to add admin also :( Please help

Comment: @SolarMike The thing is i can't enter Recovery mode, and go to utilities to Turn off Firmware Password. I am directly asked for Firmware Password when i try to goto recovery mode :(

Comment: So looks like you will be visiting a Genius bar.

Comment: @SolarMike

And there's no Genius Bar in our state. :3 Are there no other solutions ?

Comment: Before 2011, the firmware was bypassable. Since then, only Apple can unlock it. There is no workaround.

Comment: @Tetsujin
Is there any chance of reinstalling OS if i replace the current SSD installed? Or will i face the same issue?

Comment: Same issue. It is not bypassable, at all.

Comment: Oh man :3 
Also, is there any reason why CMD+S is not working while booting up? There were solutions regarding how to add admin account when there were no existing admin account

Comment: You're not going to be able to do anything that requires the firmware password… that's the entire point of the firmware lock. If you could bypass it what would be the point of it?

Comment: Provide proof of ownership to Apple and they will remove the firmware lock.